# dygraphs - how to pull in dynamic data to the left instead of overcrowding all points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, dygraphs

How is it possible to have a dynamic chart that would only display the last 10 points dynamically from the right, but the old points to get pushed to the left side of the screen and get invisible, only visible when we drag back the chart to the right/swipe to right?

Here is the live example: http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update
(also the code is jsfiddle if you hit the button)

This is what's happening after a while, the points should go to the left and remain only the last 10

[image]

Comment: perhaps is it possible to have a default - zoom to last 10 points ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the last X minutes of data, you can set the `dateWindow` property on every update. For example:

```
g.updateOptions({
  file: data,
  dateWindow: [Date.now() - 30 * 1000, Date.now()]  // last 30s.
});
```

Here's a [fully-worked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLqj2vxw/). For the last N points, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341760/dygraph-zoom-into-last-1000).

Comment: yes, this is the behavior thank you! 

But still there is some usability problems:
1. when I zoom or drag to left (back in time), I want the display to not jump back to the first point
2. when I reset the chart by right-click or double-tap, I want to see only the last 30 points not all the points since the beginning of time as it is now. 

can this be possible ?